# Why is the color of my Nav bar text not changing?

Tags: html, css

My nav bar HTML looks like:

```css
nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="second-page.html">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Why is color: red not changing the color of the li text? Shouldn't selecting nav apply changes to everything that is a child of nav as well?

Comment: Try adding `a:not(:hover) { color: inherit; }`

Comment: take a look at `!important`

Answer (score 1):

Because anchor tag `<a>` will overwrite the property color  and make it blue

```css
nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: red ;
}

/*make anchor tag red with no underline*/
a{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/*when you point by mous on it make the color green*/
a:hover{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="second-page.html">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a Anchor Tag (a) in the nav. And a tag have default property to styling, which can't be overwrite by parent nav tag.
What you have to do style the a tag separately and first remove text-decoration.
You final css will be:

```
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not change because you are styling an anchor tag that is inside un-ordered list. To do it, you should target all the anchor inside un-ordered list also list-style-type will not work on nav but work on un-ordered tag. check the snippet below

```css
nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
}

nav ul li a{
color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="second-page.html">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```